# Xen Bridge Configuration do not bridge eth1 to xenbr0

Tags: bridge, xen, para-virtualization

I am new on Para-Virtualization. I used [Xen Beginners Guide](http://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Xen_Project_Beginners_Guide) to install Xen and configure dom0 it works correctly but i cant configured bridge network for domU.

I created debian image like that.

```
xen-create-image --hostname=weblinux --vcpus=2 --lvm=vg0 --bridge=xenbr0 --ip ***.***.***.225 --pygrub --dist=wheezy
```

When xendomains service starting, peth1 interface show up. I don't know what is it. It has same mac adress with eth1.

I want to use eth1 interface for bridge domU host and eth0 for access dom0.

**xm list**

```
Name                                        ID   Mem VCPUs      State
Time(s)
Domain-0                                     0 24086    32     r-----   1091.0
weblinux                                     3  8192     2     -b----      0.2
```

**brctl show**

```
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
eth1        8000.**********43   no      peth1
xenbr0      8000.feffffffffff   no      vif3.0
```

**ifconfig**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ***:41  
      inet addr:***.***.***.82  Bcast:***.***.***.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:49365 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:3260 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:4713985 (4.4 MiB)  TX bytes:653536 (638.2 KiB)
      Interrupt:24 Memory:e6000000-e6012800 

 eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ***:43  
      inet addr:***.***.***.226  Bcast:***.***.***.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:94817 errors:0 dropped:574 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:34 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:9956941 (9.4 MiB)  TX bytes:5146 (5.0 KiB)
      Interrupt:25 Memory:e8000000-e8012800 

 peth1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ***:43  
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:10472 errors:0 dropped:62 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:72 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:1064304 (1.0 MiB)  TX bytes:6292 (6.1 KiB)
      Interrupt:25 Memory:e8000000-e8012800 

 vif3.0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  
      inet6 addr: fe80::fcff:ffff:feff:ffff/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:18 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:32 
      RX bytes:532 (532.0 B)  TX bytes:1260 (1.2 KiB)

  xenbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  
      inet6 addr: fe80::8043:dcff:fe55:d706/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:11 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:100 (100.0 B)  TX bytes:898 (898.0 B)
```

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
##eth0

allow-hotplug eth0
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp


##eth1

allow-hotplug eth1
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp

##xenbr0

iface xenbr0 inet manual
    bridge_ports eth1
```

**iptables -L**

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination        
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination    
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             PHYSDEV match --physdev-out vif3.0 --physdev-is-bridged
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             PHYSDEV match --physdev-in vif3.0 --physdev-is-bridged udp spt:bootpc dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             PHYSDEV match --physdev-out vif3.0 --physdev-is-bridged
ACCEPT     all  --  weblinux             anywhere             PHYSDEV match --physdev-in vif3.0 --physdev-is-bridged
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```